# loaded the "PersonnalDetails" nib but didn't get a UITableView

Tags: iphone

I am trying to load a new view with the following code

`- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

```
 PersonnelDetails *detailViewController = [[PersonnelDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"PersonnelDetails" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
  [detailViewController release];

}

inhertance :-  PersonnelDetails inherits UITableViewController

but i am getting an exception :

  `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "PersonnalDetails" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'`

even though i have a UITableView in the PersonnalDetails nib and also i have connected the view outlet of PersonnelDetails(viewController) to the UITableView.
 what can be the posible cause?

Comment: Typo?

There is a difference between :
<snip>initWithNibName:@"PersonnelDetails"</snip>
and
<snip>loaded the "PersonnalDetails" </snip>

Comment: The typo is there but it was consistent for the whole application. I just corrected it for this post, which now i think i should never have done.

Comment: I have the same problem but where you have the text `PersonalDetails` I have a very cryptic name: `bua-sk-pLW-view-2D1-Eq-mlN`. Also quitting Xcode did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what the problem was but after restarting the XCode, everything works fine.

Comment: Now I possibly know, that I was not saving the interface builder document explicitly. I was having a wrong idea that running the app in  iphone simulator will popup the save dialog, which will inturn also save the changes in the interface builder document. And unfortunatly this was not the case. So by closing the xcode and the interface builder i got the message to save the changes which i did and that led to the resolution of the problem.

Answer (score 16):

I think the problem is because you are subclassing UITableViewController instead of UIViewController. I had same problem before.

Answer (score 5):

This might sound strange, but in my case I really needed a UITableViewController with a table view. I am not using xib files, so I'm building all interface using code.

I was receiving the same error.

What I did was to override the loadView method just like this, and it worked!

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
}
```

What's stranger now is that if I comment the loadView method I receive another error:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key settingsView

, while the settingsView property I'm not using it and it's commented.

I'm confused now! Though with the loadView override it works.

**Edit**

I've deleted the app from my iPhone then run it again with loadView commented and it works now...

Comment: I just hit this exact same situation with an iOS 6 simulator on XCode 4.5.  How ridiculous.  But thank you for sharing!

Comment: I don't like that this fixed it for me, but it did.. so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You made mistake in your .h file,

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

or

```
@interface SearchViewController : ViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```

instead

```
@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
```