# App crash after upgrading to Xcode 4.6

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So i just upgraded my XCode to 4.6 and try running my app, and it works until i try to open a view like that:

```
 problemView *cvc=[[problemView alloc] init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];
```

In my app i use a lot identical calls but there is no problem, the problem is only with that view. I don't get any crash report after executing second line it just go to:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

When i was debugging i found out that my init method gets called and works fine, but my viewdidLoad method newer gets called. My init is preaty standard:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    self.title = @"Seznam";
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-skodnicentri.png"];
}
return self;
}
```

Any ideas? Just yesterday it was working fine...

edit:

```
 2/15/13 10:38:04.080 AM ZM[45906]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "CentriVC" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
 *** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Can you please post a complete stack trace and the output of the console?

Comment: i posted crash report from console....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, all i needed to do was add that function:

```
- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];
}
```

I got it here :[loaded the "PersonnalDetails" nib but didn't get a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633680/loaded-the-personnaldetails-nib-but-didnt-get-a-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller is of type `UITableViewController` and is expected to create a `UITableView` in loadView (ie your `view` property must be an instance of type `UITableView`). As you use a nib file for your view controller, go into Interface Builder and make sure that the `view` outlet is connected to a `UITableView` (or a subclass of `UITableView`)